# Force display inline for responsive images

Tags: css, responsive-design, inline

I need to display a grid of images 5x3. This grid needs to keep the same format and size regardless of screen resolution. The images themselves will resize responsively.

I have a list of images displayed in an inline-block like this:

```
<div class="gridView">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="">
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="">
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS is like this:

```
.gridView {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.gridView ul li {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Right now when I resize the window the grid doesn't keep it's size fixed. How do I ensure that the grid stays the same but only the images resize themselves?

Comment: why it's not working, because `width: 100%` will work for any size less than `1200px`, hence it'll keep resizing when the width is less that `1200px`. If you want it to stay static, make it `width: 1200px;` and get rid of `max-width` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to keep the layout structure the same, as in:

```
[x] [x] [x] [x] [x]

[x] [x] [x] [x] [x]

[x] [x] [x] [x] [x]
```

Then you will not require a liquid grid system, but **liquid images instead**.  What I would do is the following: Change the .gridView ul li styling so that instead of a maximum-height and width, **you set a simple height and width declaration**.

```
.gridView ul li {
height: 150px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Then add an image class to make the images responsive:

```
.img {
max-width: 100%
height: auto;
}
```

Of course, the image file sizes should be 150px x 200px at their max.

This way, your grid won't collapse as your browser width gets smaller and your images will get smaller to fit the grid.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The thing is, when I assign width: 1200px to my container, when resizing the window the grid gets eclipsed and the images don't resize themselves.

Comment: Let's create a jFiddle.  Post the code you have for now.  Instead of images, we will display blocks of color.  You'll see.

Comment: umm you mean post the code I have now into jfiddle? The thing is the images are dynamically generated via wordpress and if I only copy a portion of it, it won't load the images

Comment: That is fine, we will create a simplified version that won't use your images will be display the same structure.  What is your website?  I can get it from there.

Comment: The site is still in development on my local server. I'm creating a small color block example like you suggested before. I'll post the link here asap

Comment: Here is the link, it's really simple and for some reason I don't know it's not lining up in inline-block http://jsfiddle.net/jcyin/EFQuF/ tell me if it's enough, if not I'll edit it again. Thanks

Comment: I included the jFiddle for you.  Now, there are some stuff you may not understand, I coded this similarly to the way bootstrap uses their grid system.  This makes it possible to do things like:  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/EFQuF/4/

Comment: Amazing, thank you Raphael that's superb. Although it's the first time I see .row-fluid, since this is HTML5, will this work with older browsers? Say IE7. Please don't laugh at me, I'm doing this for a client that has a lot of legacy users

Comment: oh, my bad sorry didn't get to this part "Bootstrap was made to not only look and behave great in the latest desktop browsers (as well as IE7!)" That solves my small issue. Thanks again Raphael, you're amazing! :)

Comment: I am happy to hear that you liked it.  That being said, what I would do is instead of coding this on my own, LEARN how this code is being used and then instead of doing all this work, use bootstrap.  Trust me, it will save you TONS of time in the long run.  First download html5boilerplate and then add the CSS files to bootstrap.  I am working on an eCommerce site myself and this is the road I am taking.  Actually, if you want to keep in touch for ideas and design, let me know, since maybe you will run into a problem that I have.  This same issue you face was one I faced a few weeks ago.

Comment: Sorry, add the CSS froms FROM bootstrap into the CSS folder in the html5boilerplate.

Comment: And it will save you time in the sense that you know that cross browser issues are solved.

Comment: yea exactly that's what I'm planning to do. Thanks for letting me know this amazing new trick. I never knew it even existed, guess I gotta read less gizmodo and more programming blogs to be up to date. I'd like to keep in touch, although I'm kinda new to stackoverflow so I don't know how to contact other users

Comment: my email is persianturtle@gmail.com

Comment: My hope is that since we are doing similar projects, I may be able to learn as well!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24328/discussion-between-user2028856-and-raphael-rafatpanah)

Answer (score 0):

width: 100%; will always change size of element relative to parent element/window.
for fixed width you need fixed width. Simple as that
like:

```
width: 1200px;
```

Comment: The thing is, when I assign width: 1200px, when resizing the window the grid gets eclipsed and the images don't resize themselves.

Comment: it's hard to imagine what you mean, but I think, that images will not resize themselves because element can be resized only relative to parent element. As long some of your parent element will be fixed, everything will be fixed. Well at least with css only. JS maybe can deal with it

Comment: It's not the resize part that's not working for me, the images resize fine. However it's the parent container which has issues. I should have rephrased the question, the container doesn't force keep the same layout. Rather than keeping 5x3 and then forcing images to resize, the layout becomes 4x5, then 3x6 etc until its 1x7. I need it to keep 5x3 all the way